# OCI ObjectStorage uploading an object while it is being read

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface, object-storage, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Lets say I have a large object stored in ObjectStorage (in MBs) --

What will happen now if someone (lets say connection A) tries to retrieve it (downloading it) while someone else (lets say connection B) is updating the object by uploading a new version of blob into the same object?

Will connection A still see the old version while the new version of blob has not completely uploaded or will see a corrupted data? At what time A will start seeing the new version of the object?

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading an object while it is overwritten you will continue to see the old object.

The system does out-of-place overwrites so the old data is available *however* if the download goes on for a very long time the old data will be garbage collected and the download will fail (this is a very extreme scenario)